# Layout woes with GridView rotation

Tags: android, gridview, layout

My aim is to have a screen which has a top section as a textView, a bottom section as a button, and a middle section that acts like a horizontal scrolling grid.
Using a fragment with a gridView that's rotated 270, and rotating each item 90 has gotten me close to what I'm attempting to achieve...however I'm struggling with these layout issues which you can see in the pic:

[image]

1) altering the height of the fragment will cause the 1st row of items to be partially clipped

2) the width of the gridView does scroll to the right as desired, but the visible right edge of the gridView is not aligned to the right edge of the screen

3) I'd like to adjust the space between the top and bottom rows of the grid, I'd expect to do this by altering the height of the gridView, however adjusting the height of the gridView or fragment also alters the width

4) Using the typical combination of layout_weight with 0dp set for height isn't working, as the fragment will not adjust it's height to the stated weight...also width shrinks too. To get to the view in the attached pic, I had to add fixed heights in dp in activity_my.xml

Here's my code...

**activity_my.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/top_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:lines="1"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:text="First text block"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.50" />

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:name="com.example.horizontalgrid2.MAFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_ma"
        android:background="#ff8c8c00"
        android:layout_weight="0.35"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:text="Second text block"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.15"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment_ma.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/tablegrid"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
        android:rotation="270"
        android:numColumns="2"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

**item_caller_grid.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:rotation="90">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            >
        </ImageView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Name"
            android:layout_below="@+id/grid_item_image"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MyActivity.java**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    }
}
```

**MAFragment.java**

```
public class MAFragment extends Fragment {

    private View view;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ma, container, false);
        GridView gridview = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.tablegrid);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity()));

        return view;
    }

}
```

**ImageAdapter.java**

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View gridView;

        if (convertView == null) {

            gridView = new View(mContext);

            gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_caller_grid, null);

            // set image based on selected text
            imageView = (ImageView) gridView
                    .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);


            imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);


        } else {
            gridView = (View) convertView;
        }

        return gridView;
    }

    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher
    };
}
```

Comment: hey !! you solved it ..plzz paste your answer here... for others to get helped.